# How do I delete user data from firebase after deleting a user in react-native-firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I want to delete a user and all the user data in react-native-firebase upon request of the user. The user data is stored in a firebase realtime DB and can only be manipulated by the authenticated user. Both delete actions individually are easy to do. However, I'm facing the following problem now:

Firebase requires a recent login in order to delete the account. Hence, the delete operation only works if the user recently logged in. Otherwise, I must return an error and ask the user to relog before trying again. For this reason, I should not delete the user data before I have confirmation that the account was deleted successfully, or otherwise, I might end up with a user account with no data. After the account was deleted, the request to delete user data does not come from the authenticated user anymore (because it was deleted), hence the user doesn't have permission anymore to delete their own data.

In principle I would need to either simultaneously delete the user and the data or trigger a cloud function to react to the user being deleted. Any ideas on how I could accomplish that?